# Trying to change img src if another element is visible with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div ("panel" class) on my page that toggles open/closed on the click of a paragraph element ("flip" class), which has an image inside of it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="panel">Contact info</div>
<p class="flip"><img src="images/contactExpand.png" />Expand</p>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Everything works fine so far, but I want the image src to change to "contactCollapse.png" when the panel div is visible. This doesn't seem to do anything (image just stays the same):

```
if ($(".panel").is(":visible") == true) {
    $(".flip img").attr("src","../images/contactCollapse.png")
}
else {
    $(".flip img").attr("src","../images/contactExpand.png")
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to check at the *end* of the animation, as it'll be visible at the start no matter which direction you're animating, like this:

```
$(".flip").click(function(){
  $(".panel").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".flip img").attr("src", $(this).is(":visible")
        ? "../images/contactCollapse.png"
        : "../images/contactExpand.png");
  });
});
```

Comment: just to add to this answer, this is the concept of a callback function, executing after the original function completes.  Very useful to chain actions together in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the URL is correct?  You have `images/contactExpand.png` in the original code and `../images/contactExpand.png` in your javascript.

Also - are your sure this code works correctly? `$(".panel").is(":visible") == true`.  Maybe if you change it to `$(".panel:visible").length == 1`.

Comment: For the URL, my javascript is inside a folder so I needed to navigate back up a directory. However, I tried changing the URL and it still didn't change anything, so I don't think the jQuery code is even working at all. I tried changing the code to what you suggested and it still wasn't changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the status isn't change until after the slide is performed. Try placing your code in the callback of the slideToggle:

```
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow",function(){
        if ($(".panel").is(":visible")) {
            $(".flip img").attr("src","../images/contactCollapse.png")
        }
        else {
            $(".flip img").attr("src","../images/contactExpand.png")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @NIckCraver hit it before I did, didn't get the "There is an answer already posted" message while I was composing. ;p

Comment: Yes that solution (as well as your version) worked. Thank you!